# Multiple push clear issue in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to display push notification using gcm in android.
i am getting push notification from sever, notification is showing in system tray
one after another, means first notification first and second notification second and so on.

the following is my code for generating push notification

```
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) 
{

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);



     String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home_Activity.class);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     notificationIntent.putExtra("language", "English");
     PendingIntent intent =
             PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

     notificationManager.cancelAll();
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

     // Play default notification sound
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

     //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

     // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;


     //notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      
     notificationManager.notify((int)Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1, notification);
```

now when user clicks on any push notification in system tray all the notification should be clear, how can u achieve this?

Comment: That's a strange UI behavior. If you choose to display all notifications in the system tray (instead of only displaying the newest), it doesn't make sense to clear them all when you click on one of them. Perhaps you should only display the newest notification and override the previous notification if exists. You can configure it to clear automatically when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
In onclick event you can implement `notificationManager.cancelAll();`
```

Hope this helps.